# Task Scheduler freezes when Properties is clicked on the Actions pane even after sfc/scannow and reboot; but opening a second Task Scheduler succeeds

Tags: windows-10, freeze, windows-task-scheduler

When I open Task Scheduler on Windows 10, choose a task, and then click on Properties in the Actions pane, the Task Scheduler GUI freezes. I can still work with other things on the desktop. So I run sfc/scannow, reboot gracefully, and try once again. Task Scheduler again freezes when I click on Properties for the chosen task. But if I open a second instance of Task Scheduler leaving the first instance frozen like that, I'm able to click on Properties in the Actions pane for the very same task and make edits to the task.  If this is known behavior and there's a fix, what is it? Thanks

Comment: Try running DISM ahead of SFC.   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Trying that now, thanks.  Image Version 10.0.19041.1415 now at 55%

Comment: I took the two DISM steps and sfc/scannow and rebooted. Some short-lived progress. The Task Scheduler GUI still froze up when I clicked Properties  for a chosen task.  After a minute  the Task Scheduler GUI "thawed" so to speak, and I was able to drag the window and resize it, and I clicked on Properties and the edit dialog opened.  I closed the dialog.  Then I clicked on Properties again, and now it's frozen again, and has been frozen for about 5 minutes.

Comment: I am not certain.  Make a new, test, Windows User Account (Profile). Try Task Scheduler in the new Windows Profile.

Comment: I am unable to create a new profile on the Windows 10 PC in question, which is on a company LAN.  Windows is demanding a phone number or email address for the "person" who is being given access to the computer.

Comment: I had something similar when adding credentials to a task to allow it when a user's not logged in.  The issue turned out to be related to terminal services trying to interact with the yubikey on my client.  More here; https://serverfault.com/a/1120027/137255